# Angular 2 error: '/detail/:id' conflicts with existing route '/detail/:id'

Tags: angular

So I've been building an app to learn about Angular 2 and ran into this problem in the Terminal:

```
    app/teacher-detail.component.ts(17,3): error TS2369: A parameter property is only allowed in a constructor implementation.
    [0] app/teacher-detail.component.ts(18,3): error TS2369: A parameter property is only allowed in a constructor implementation.
    [0] app/teacher-detail.component.ts(23,19): error TS2339: Property '_routeParams' does not exist on type 'TeacherDetailComponent'.
    [0] app/teacher-detail.component.ts(24,8): error TS2339: Property '_teacherService' does not exist on type 'TeacherDetailComponent'.
```

Now, I can't seem to find the problem. My other list (student-detail.component.ts) is formatted almost exactly like this list, but no error pops up.

```
import {Component, Input, OnInit} from 'angular2/core';
import { RouteParams } from 'angular2/router';

import {Teacher} from './teacher';
import { TeacherService } from './teacher.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-teacher-detail',
  templateUrl:'app/teacher-detail.component.html',
})

export class TeacherDetailComponent implements OnInit {
@Input() teacher: Teacher;


contructor(
    private _teacherService: TeacherService,
    private _routeParams: RouteParams) {

    }

ngOnInit() {
    let id =  +this._routeParams.get('id');
    this._teacherService.getTeacher(id)
        .then(teacher => this.teacher = teacher);
}
goBack() {
window.history.back();
}
```

}

Looking in Chrome Dev Tools, I see THIS:

```
EXCEPTION: Error: Uncaught (in promise): EXCEPTION: Error during instantiation of Router! (RouterLink -> Router).
ORIGINAL EXCEPTION: Configuration '/detail/:id' conflicts with existing route '/detail/:id'
ORIGINAL STACKTRACE:
Error: Configuration '/detail/:id' conflicts with existing route '/detail/:id'
```

Which made me think, is it in my app file in the @RouteConfig?

```
@RouteConfig([
{
    path: '/dashboard',
    name: 'Dashboard',
    component: DashboardComponent,
    useAsDefault: true
},
{
    path: '/detail/:id',
    name: 'TeacherDetail',
    component: TeacherDetailComponent
},
{
    path: '/detail/:id',
    name: 'StudentDetail',
    component: StudentDetailComponent
},
{
    path: '/teachers',
    name: 'Teachers',
    component: TeachersComponent

},
{
    path: '/students',
    name: 'Students',
    component: StudentsComponent
},
])
```

I'm totally stuck, and can't figure out what the problem is. I suspect it has something to do with the /detail/id thing, but not sure how to proceed since deleting one of them doesn't fix the problem overall.

Thanks for your help in advance!

Comment: Well, you must at least remove one of the mappings: you can't have two different routes with the exact same URL. What happens precisely when you do that?

Comment: Ok, so I removed the /detail/id with the StudentDetail name. I can navigate from the Dashboard to the Teacher now, although obviously navigating to the Student link gives nothing back.

If I remove the Teacher version, clicking the Student link still gives nothing back (could be a different error, will check later)

However, I am still running into that same error that shows up in Terminal.

Comment: Typo: `contructor` should be `constructor`. Voting to close as typo

Answer (score 1):

Ok, thanks to JB Nizet for helping me out.

Today I learned I cant have two paths with the same path in the Router. I'll have to figure out a different way to route this particular section of the app.

Also... he found a typo (contructor instead of constructor).

Yes, forehead met table. Several times. Staring at code for three hours last night and I never caught it.

Thanks for your help JB Nizet.